# Flash playing SWF, video is normal sound is sped up half way on 4th scene

Tags: flash, audio, flash-cs4, overlap

When I play each individual scene as an SWF all the sounds are synced correctly, but  when I play the entire animation that half way through on scene 4 the sounds play too early and are also sped up about 2X regular speed.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you explain how you have your Flash file setup because on the timeline you can add sound to a layer in several different ways, streaming being one. So if for example you have your video locked to the frames and your sound is streaming then its likely they will go out of sync pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For each of my sounds I have a seperate layer above the rest of the time line with a start and stop button I have tried to stream it and the other option in that category I can't remember.  Also this in on CS4 and action script 3 if that helps. What are some different ways I can

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionScript at the start of each scene to play the sound which you'll add to the library and export to ActionScript.